# How do I model a record's fields as data?

Tags: haskell, record

Let's say I have a `Person` record with some fields:

```
data Person = Person
  { name :: String
  , age :: Int
  , id :: Int
  }
```

and I want to be able to search a list of `Person`s by a given field:

```
findByName :: String -> [Person] -> Maybe Person
findByName s = find (\p -> name p == s)
```

Now let's say I want to be able to model and store these searches/queries as data, for instance for logging purposes, or to batch execute them, or whatever.

How would I go about representing a search over a given field (or set of fields) as data?

My intuition says to model it as a map of fields to string values (`Map (RecordField) (Maybe String)`), but I can't do that, because record fields are functions.

Is there a better way to do this than, say, the following?

```
data PersonField = Name | Age | Int

type Search = Map PersonField (Maybe String)
```

This could technically work but it decouples `PersonField` from `Person` in an ugly way.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to serialize these query objects to disk, then your "field" type is `Person -> a`. A record accessor is just a function from `Person` to some type `a`. Or if you end up outgrowing basic accessors and need to work with a lot of nested data, you can look into [lenses](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens).

However, it sounds like you want to be able to write these queries to disk. In that case, you can't easily serialize functions (or lenses, for that matter). I don't know of a way built-in to Haskell to do all of that automatically and still have it be serializable. So my recommendation would be to roll your own datatypes.

```
data PersonField = Name | Age | Id
```

or, even better, you can use [GADTs](https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/GADT) to keep type safety.

```
data PersonField a where
  Name :: PersonField String
  Age  :: PersonField Int
  Id   :: PersonField Int

getField :: PersonField a -> Person -> a
getField Name = name
getField Age  = age
getField Id   = id
```

Then you have total control over this concrete type and can write your own serialization logic for it. I think `Map PersonField (Maybe String)` is a good start, and you can refine the `Maybe String` part if you end up doing more complex queries (like "contains" or "case insensitive comparison", for instance).

Comment: I guess Cloud Haskell automates serialization and deserialization (yes, even of functions and closures)... but I don't know whether it exposes enough stuff to serialize to *disk* rather than to the network.

Comment: @DanielWagner Might be wrong, but my memory from when I looked into Cloud Haskell was that it didn't really serialise the actual function definitions, just gave them canonical identifiers so a program executing on the other side of the network cloud be told which function to execute (or to build a closure for), on the assumption that it would be compiled in to that program as well.

Comment: @Ben Just a quick thought exercise: read that comment back, and work out which bits are *not* a good description of the `PersonField` in this answer.

Comment: @DanielWagner Yes, but if you do it yourself you get to pick human-readable canonical identifiers, and you get to decide whether different versions of the software agree on the identifiers. Cloud Haskell's identification of functions is auto-generated for the purpose of one binary talking to another copy of itself; is there any guarantee the canonical identifier of `name :: Person -> String` isn't just `0xaf32aca7` (or whatever)? Or that it stays the same if you make a small change and recompile?

Answer (score 2):

> I want to be able to model and store these searches/queries as data

Let's assume we want to store them as JSON. We could define a type like

```
data Predicate record = Predicate {
    runPredicate :: record -> Bool ,
    storePredicate :: Value
}
```

Where `storePredicate` would return a JSON representation of the "reference value" inside the predicate. For example, the value 77 for "age equals 77".

For each record, we would like to have a collection like this:

```
type FieldName = String
type FieldPredicates record = [(FieldName, Value -> Maybe (Predicate record))]
```

That is: for each field, we can supply a JSON value encoding the "reference value" of the predicate and, if it parses successfully, we get a `Predicate`. Otherwise we get `Nothing`. This would allows us to serialize and deserialize predicates.

We could define `FieldPredicates` manually for each record, but is there a more automated way? We could try generating field equality predicates using a typeclass. But first, the extensions and imports dance:

```
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneKindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE BlockArguments #-}
import Data.Functor ( (<&>) )
import Data.Kind ( Type, Constraint )
import Data.Proxy
import GHC.Records ( HasField(..) )
import GHC.TypeLits ( KnownSymbol, Symbol, symbolVal )
import Data.Aeson ( FromJSON(parseJSON), Value, ToJSON(toJSON) )
import Data.Aeson.Types (parseMaybe)
import Data.List ( lookup )
```

Now we define the helper typeclass:

```
type HasEqFieldPredicates :: [Symbol] -> Type -> Constraint
class HasEqFieldPredicates fieldNames record where
  eqFieldPredicates :: FieldPredicates record

instance HasEqFieldPredicates '[] record where
  eqFieldPredicates = []

instance
  ( KnownSymbol fieldName, 
    HasField fieldName record v,
    Eq v,
    FromJSON v,
    ToJSON v,
    HasEqFieldPredicates fieldNames record
  ) =>
  HasEqFieldPredicates (fieldName ': fieldNames) record
  where
  eqFieldPredicates =
    let current =
          ( symbolVal (Proxy @fieldName), 
          \j ->
              parseMaybe (parseJSON @v) j <&> \v ->
                  Predicate (\record -> getField @fieldName record == v) (toJSON v))
    in current : eqFieldPredicates @fieldNames @record
```

An example with `Person`:

```
personEqPredicates :: [(FieldName, Value -> Maybe (Predicate Person))]
personEqPredicates = eqFieldPredicates @["name", "age", "id"] @Person

personAgeEquals :: Value -> Maybe (Predicate Person)
personAgeEquals = let Just x = Data.List.lookup "age" personEqPredicates in x
```

Putting it to work:

```
ghci> let Just p = personAgeEquals (toJSON (77::Int)) in runPredicate p Person { name = "John", age = 78, id = 3 }
False
ghci> let Just p = personAgeEquals (toJSON (78::Int)) in runPredicate p Person { name = "John", age = 78, id = 3 }
True
```